# phpMailer to gmail business from Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, gmail, phpmailer

I've been trying to set up google business email smtp. I've created an account with my own email address (username@mydomain.me). This is hosted by gmail.

I'm using the phpMailer class on Heroku. I've already uncommented the php_openssl.dll in the php.ini file.

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
 ...
 $mail->Host = "ssl://stmp.gmail.com";
 $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
 $mail->Port       = 587;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
 $mail->Username   = "username@myDomain.me";
 $mail->Password   = "mypassword";
 $mail->SetFrom('username@myDomain.me', '...');
 $mail->AddReplyTo("an@email.co", '');
 $mail->Subject = '...';
 ...
```

Comment: $mail->Host = "ssl://stmp.gmail.com"; check this in doc, I feel that is wrong, ssl might be directed separately

Comment: saw it as ssl in several blog articles... we initially had it w/o.

Comment: @NewBee, We did define PHPMailer, just not in the excerpt, sorry. We have the line $Mail->Port = 587, is that the problem?

Comment: We have SMTPSecure, its up in the code I gave.

Comment: see updated answer, port needs to be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out! The trick was "tls" not ssl!

```
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.mydomain.me"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "name@mydomain.me";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "pass";            // GMAIL password
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

should work

reference :- [1](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)  [2](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail)

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; and see what happens exactly

Comment: then sorry bro, go for hunting php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: , might help you

Comment: think of upvoting it to help me out? Thanks for trying.

Comment: did you solved your issue? if yes, please update the answer or add your own answer

Comment: Finally figured it out! I'll post in a second.